# How to shuffle/ randomize an array and display randomed entries in php

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

Good  afternoon,

I am looking for a solution already few days,
have seen a lot of material regarding shuffle and rand_array
on stackoverflow and other pages, but could not find the right solution for me.

Iam working on dynamical content for a web project.
With the code down I am getting the data for an array $prodItems and the code is working fine.

Currently I am receiving all data (over 1000+)
Titles and images of products.

What I want to get is - to display a random number (for Example 5 or 10)
of $prod_id

With other words to display randomly 5 or 10 titles and pages of products instead of 1000+

I will be very thanksful if someboday could give me a code example.

```
foreach ($prodItems as $prod_id => $item) { ?>
    <?php echo $prod_id; ?>
    <?php echo $item["image"]; ?>
    <?php echo $item["title"]; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Here ias a Example of the array if requested.

```
<?php
$prodItems = array(

        "prod1" => array(
                "title" => "example title 1",
                "image" => "path to the image 1" 
            ),
        
        "prod2" => array(
                "title" => "example title 2",
                "image" => "path to the image 2" 
            ),     
        
         "prod3" => array(
                "title" => "example title 3",
                "image" => "path to the image 3" 
            ),
     );   
?>
```

Comment: Why terminate the `?>` PHP tags only to open a new one as the very next thing you do??

Comment: Shuffling your array on its own won’t do the trick, if you then still foreach over the complete shuffled array - that will still get you all 1000 items, only in random order. Either extract the first x items from your shuffled array (research please, if you don’t know how to) and then loop over that - or implement a counter variable in your foreach loop, so that you can `break` out of it, once you reached the desired number of iterations.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just start learning php, and "?>" what I have seen in code exampels.

Comment: Please dont use wordpress as an example of readable/maintainable code

Comment: Take a look at [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). You can provide it the array of products and a number which will select number keys (thus product ids). I'de highly recommend trying to use this function yourself or the approach @CBroe suggested since these can be alright learning experiences for things you might want to do more often in the future or for other projects.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I do not want to use wordpress that why I am doing the project. I have been as well not looking at any wordpress sources for examples. If you can give a suggestion how to solve - you are very welcome.

Comment: @CBroe  thank you I will research and try.

Comment: @Remy I was already trying with array-rand will look at that again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`array_rand()` seems like a perfect tool in this case

```
$prodItems = [  'aa88' => ['title'   => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'bb44' => ['title'   => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'cc345' => ['title'  => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'dd777' => ['title'  => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'ee435f' => ['title' => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'ff1df4' => ['title' => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'gg2ss' => ['title'  => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'hh4' => ['title'    => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'ii2' => ['title'    => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy'],
                'jj7' => ['title'    => 'xxx',  'image' => 'yyy']

    ];

$ShowMe = 3;
$rand_keys = array_rand($prodItems , $ShowMe));
print_r($rand_keys);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => dd777
    [1] => ff1df34
    [2] => gg2ss
)
```

Then just use this array to pick occurances from your large array

```
foreach ($rand_keys as $key){
    echo $key;
    echo $prodItems[$key]['title'];
    echo $prodItems[$key]['image'];
}
```

Comment: many thanks, it was exactly what I needed! Have a nice day.